# Angular directives link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, jqlite

I'm new to Angular. I was trying to learn directives. In my directive's `link` function I log my element and see that its an array. why it's an array?

```
<mouse-enter>HI</mouse-enter>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('custom.directive').directive('mouseEnter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            console.log(element);// this line prints an array!
            element[0].onmouseover = function () {
                console.log('Mouse Entered!');
            };
        }
    }
});
```

In which case this array's length can be more than 1!!

Comment: jquery/jqLite selectors always return arrays - which is what 'element' is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular's jQlite selectors is an alias of jQuery function when jQuery is available otherwise jQlite will be an Angular's inbuilt small subset of jQuery.

So jQlite or jQuery selector always returns array.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Consider the following DOM structure:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="foo bar" id="dom-element-1">Hello</div>
    <p>ignore me</p>
</div>

<span class="foo" id="dom-element-2">Hello again</div>
```

Now when you do either of this: `$(".foo")` or `angular.element(document.querySelectAll(".foo"))`, you will get a jQlite or jQuery instance which will be an array of two dom elements with IDs **dom-element-1** and **dom-element-2**.

Comment: array of what?Can you please give me a DOM structure that will provide more than one value in that array?

Comment: @antiMatter, I've updated the answer with an example of the same.